# Sequelize M:N association not creating through table record

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js, associations

When I create a recipe with associated tags using the through option, no record is created in the joining table in the mysql database I'm connected to.

Here are my models definitions:

```
export const Recipe = sequelize.define('Recipe', {
    // Model attributes are defined here
    title: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    image: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true
    },
    prepTime: {
        type: DataTypes.DOUBLE,
        allowNull: false
    },
    cookTime: {
        type: DataTypes.DOUBLE,
        allowNull: false
    },
    totalTime: {
        type: DataTypes.DOUBLE,
        allowNull: false
    },
    servings: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    },
    rating: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    },
    notes: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: true
    },
}, {
    // Other model options go here
    tableName: 'Recipes'
});

export const Tag = sequelize.define('Tag', {
    // Model attributes are defined here
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
}, {
    // Other model options go here
    tableName: 'Tags'
});

export const RecipeTag = sequelize.define('RecipeTag', {
    // Model attributes are defined here
}, {
    // Other model options go here
    timestamps: false,
    tableName: 'RecipeTags'
});
```

Here are my associations:

```
Recipe.belongsToMany(Tag, {
    through: RecipeTag,
    foreignKey: 'recipeId',
    as: 'tags'
})

Tag.belongsToMany(Recipe, {
    through: RecipeTag,
    foreignKey: 'tagId',
    as: 'recipes'
})
```

Here is the create call:

```
Recipe.create(args, {
                model: Tag,
                through: RecipeTag,
                as: 'tags'
            });
```

And here is the data:

```
{
  "title": "Test Recipe",
  "image": "test",
  "prepTime": 20,
  "cookTime": 40,
  "totalTime": 60,
  "servings": 2,
  "rating": 5,
  "categoryId": 1,
  "tags": [
    {
      "name": "New tag",
      "id": 1
    }
  ],
}
```

With this set up the create method only creates a new recipe. How can I use the create method to add a record to the joining RecipeTags table at the same time as creating a new recipe? I've managed to get it working by doing something like this:

```
args.tags.map(async (tag: { tagId: number }) => {
    await RecipeTag.create({tagId: tag.tagId, recipeId: recipe.id})
});
```

But I'd rather have it done in the create if it's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the association options with `include`.

```js
Recipe.create(args, {
    include: {
        model: Tag,
        through: RecipeTag,
        as: 'tags'
    }
});
```

**UPDATE:**

In order to prevent the duplicates, you can add `ignoreDuplicates` option and data must include the primary key value.

```json
{
  "title": "Test Recipe",
  ...
  "tags": [
    {
      "name": "New tag",
      "id": 1   # this is important
    }
  ]
}
```

Then

```js
Recipe.create(args, {
    include: {
        model: Tag,
        through: RecipeTag,
        as: 'tags',
        ignoreDuplicates: true  // Add this
    }
});
```

There were some bugs for this option, I suggest you to use the newer version of Sequelize, if you haven't updated lately.

Comment: Using this creates a new tag... is there a way to not create a new tag and only create a record in the through table referencing an already existing tag?

Comment: @Sheldon I updated my answer, please check.

Comment: it worked, thank you!