# Sequelize: Special methods don't update the database? - Problem updating instance

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I've spent a decent chunk of the day confused about the behaviour of one of my methods that should create an instance of a Model, `Company`, that has a `Contact`.

I feel like it should be simple, but it's just not outputting the `contact` field as I'd expect, even though it is saving it to the database correctly:

```
await sequelize.transaction(async (t) => {

    const company = await Company.create({ name: req.body.companyName }, { transaction: t });
    const contact = await Contact.create({position: req.body.position}, { transaction: t });
        
    await company.addContact(contact, {transaction: t}); // This method does exist
    await company.save(); // Thought this might help in case `addContact` didn't update the db

    console.log(company.dataValues);   // {id:5, name: 'test'}
    console.log(contact.dataValues);   // {id: 7, position: 'Legend'}

    const test = await Company.findOne({where: { name: req.body.companyName }, transaction: t});
    console.log(test.dataValues);   // {id: 5, name: 'test'}, no contact property
    console.log(company.contacts); // is this not posssible instead?

//...
```

I was expecting this as the output:

{
id: 5,
name: 'test',
contacts: [{ id: 7, position: 'legend' }]
}

Really can't understand why it's not working. Any help would be really appreciated at this point!

** Associations:

```
Company.hasMany(Contact);
Contact.belongsTo(Company);
```

Comment: Could you add the association code of `Company` and `Contact`?

Comment: Hi @Emma - yeah sure, thanks for taking a look. I've not had any problems calling say `Company.findByPk(req.body.id, { include:[{model:Contact}] })` in other methods. So I think the association is ok?

Comment: I take that back - I'm now getting problems in other areas, despite them having worked for months, and as recently as last night. I've not (as far as I'm aware) touched anything RE associations. Ugh.  :(

Comment: i see. so this might not be a solution but in your code, you are missing `include` in `findOne` for `test` which won't get any contacts info.

Comment: That's definitely part of my problem - I'm so tired I completely missed that. Thanks. I'll have to work on the rest of it tommorow. Out of interest - do sequelize's special methods, like `addContact` above, update the database straight away, or do I have to save the model after? Thanks again for your help

Comment: oh, and - the whole reason why I got into this mess - do I have to do that second select query in order to access the `contacts`? (rather than just trying to access them via `company.contacts` ?)

Comment: `addContact` will do UPDATE query to DB and you don't need `save`.  for the second question, since you are separating the `create`, perhaps it is better to query with find.  If you want to skip these hassles and create in both tables with 1 function, try something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/71913937/2956135.  the link is for `belongsToMany` but you can do similar things for `hasMany` with a little adjustment.

Comment: I'll defintely look at the create 2 in 1 option - thanks. Not sure I quite understood your answer to the second question though. Are you saying that yes, it is better to query the db for a second time to get the model instance? I'm guessing `company.contacts` doesn't work because the `company` object was created before the `contact` child was added? I tried to use `company.reload()`, but then realised I was just guessing XD